# Custom tab bar view in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to do this view(tab bar)
[image]

i dont know how to do such outline
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have t define the TabBar in the Appbar and the content of the tabs in the body with TabBarView:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DefaultTabController(
  initialIndex: 1,
  length: 3,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('TabBar Widget'),
      bottom: const TabBar(
        tabs: <Widget>[
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access_sharp),
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: const TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('It\'s cloudy here'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('It\'s rainy here'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('It\'s sunny here'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}